# How do you create in-line commenting in SQL (with SQL-Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, comments

What if I want to make a comment within a single line in SQL? Can I do something like(to temporarily get rid of "TargetName":

```
select SessionSID, TargetID, /* TargetName,*/ FEDSurveyName, 
SupplierID,ClientLK_ResponseStatusID from BI_Sessions (nolock)
         WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN '05-15-2012' AND '05-16-2012'
                 AND SupplierID = 336 

hcirt erom on
```

Does any version of SQL allow us to do such commenting(preferably MSSQL)?

Comment: Did you try it?  MS SQL I believe allows exactly this.

Comment: This is a select. There is no harm in running it, and it will run, as it is typed. You're getting down votes because you didn't try exactly what you have typed in, which is proof you didn't try to figure this out yourself first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, MSSQL allows it exactly as you've formatted it. But this will work, too:

```
select SessionSID
, TargetID
--, TargetName
, FEDSurveyName 
, SupplierID
, ClientLK_ResponseStatusID 
from BI_Sessions (nolock)
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN '05-15-2012' AND '05-16-2012'
AND SupplierID = 336
```

Answer (score 4):

Your exact query parses just fine.  That comment `/* Your commented text here */` is legal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about MSSQL, but Oracle SQL allows exactly the kind of in-line comment you show in your example.